# FaultException<T>() exception thrown by the service is not caught by the client catch(FaultException<T>)

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, faultcontract

Ok, I know I am missing something here. I have the following operation contract:

```
public double DivideByZero(int x, int y)
{                   
    if (y == 0) 
    { 
        throw new FaultException<ArgumentException>
          (new ArgumentException("Just some dummy exception")
          ,new FaultReason("some very bogus reason"), new FaultCode("007"));
    }
    return x / y;
}
```

And following is taken from the client:-

```
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the x value");
  string x = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the Y value");
  string y = Console.ReadLine();
  try
  {
      double val = client.DivideByZero(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));
      Console.WriteLine("The result is " + val.ToString());
  }
  catch(FaultException<ArgumentException> exp)  
  {
      Console.WriteLine("An ArgumentException was thrown by the service "+ exp.ToString());    
  }
  catch (Exception exp)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
  }
```

In the above case  catch(FaultException exp) (the first catch block with ArgumentException in the client code) block does not get executed. However, when I remove ArgumentException to have catch(FaultException exp), the same catch block gets executed. I am not sure about this as I am throwing FaultException from my operation contract. Am I missing anything here.

Appreciate your help,
Ashish

**EDIT :- When I updated the service reference in my client, I was able to catch the `FaultException<ArgumentException>` exception.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with `FaultException<DataContract>` for some arbitrary data contract type. If you look at the generated code for the fault in the proxy class, I bet you'll see that the `ArgumentException` is not serializing the way you expect it to.

Comment: Absolutely. If you have a custom exception class and use that to throw and catch, It does work. Not sure why it wont work (serialize) with ArgumentException.

Comment: @Ashish: there is no reason for `Exception` to serialize using the DataContractSerializer. Do not use exceptions as the fault type. They will not appear properly as SOAP Faults to clients. This is not what SOAP Faults are about.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am very new to WCF and do realize now that you probably would use your custom exception class as DataContract rather than using the system "Exception" (or its classes).

Comment: @Ashish: also, did you declare your faults using `[FaultContract]`?

Comment: I did. Also, now I am looking at it and see that FaultException<ArgumentException> does work when I updated the service reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deriving Exception class, make sure that your custom exception has the serialization constructor

```
protected MyCustomException(
          SerializationInfo info,
          StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) { }
```